# Deploying simple scala app(non-webapp) managed with maven

Tags: maven-2, deployment, scala, maven

I am new to the java/scala stack in general. So far I have a relatively simple scala application (not a webapp) setup and built build with maven2, and I'd like to be able to deploy the output to one or more production server (ubuntu on EC2, but that shouldn't matter I assume)?

My main questions are:
1) What's the best way to get all the dependent (third-party) jars installed on the production server? maven takes care of installing them on my development box, how does that work in prod?
2) I can run my app with mvn scala:run, but what's the right way to start the app in production?
3) How do I deal with subsequent deployments?

Any pointers/resources will be appreiated! Thanks a bunch in advance for helping a noob! :)

Comment: Is this Lift, by any chance? You speak of the dependencies as if you didn't know exactly what they are.

Comment: I was just assuming they don't matter. A few packages like twitter4j, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to use the Maven [App Assembler plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) to package dependencies, my own code, and create startup scripts. Basic use is described in the excellent [Maven book](http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/customizing-sect-custom-packaged.html) from Sonatype.

For the most flexibility, it can generate Java Service Wrapper scripts, which allow the application to be run either as a command line application, a Windows Service, or a Unix Daemon.

This approach is not specific to Scala applications. You just need to know the main class of your application, e.g. sample.Main$ in the code below.

```
package sample

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = println("hello world")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

retronym's answer looks like the best solution but if you just want something really simple you can use the Maven [assembly](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/howto.html) plugin. All you do is add it as a plugin to you pom.xml then do `mvn assembly:assembly` and it will build you a jar with all your dependencies (including scala lib) unjared into it. So you can then just run your application with `java -cp my.jar MyMainClass`.